# Can't explain behaviour of examples executed in the scala shell

Tags: debugging, shell, scala, actor

L.S.

I'm just learning Scala using "Programming in Scala" by Odersky et al.

In the chapter on actors I ran in to behaviour I can't explain. More specifically when trying to send a message to 'self' (see also [example](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/actors-and-concurrency.html#30.3))

Entering in the Scala shell:

```
scala> import scala.actors.Actor._  
import scala.actors.Actor._
scala > self ! "Hello"

scala > self.receive { case x => x }
```

But the last line doesn't 'return' with the expected answer:

```
resX:Any = hello
```

In need to do a Ctrl-C to get the shell back accepting my input and returns the message that:

```
Execution interrupted by signal.

scala> self.receive {case x => x}
// She's gone rogue, captain! Have to take her out!
// Calling Thread.stop on runaway Thread[Thread-54,5,main] with offending code:
// scala> self.receive {case x => x}
```

But the following actually works:

```
self ! "Hello" ; self.receive { case x => x }
```

My questions is:

What's happening? Why doesn't the first example work and the second does?!? 
I would like to understand the behaviour of the shell a bit better as the authors of the book claim that using self as the recipient of answers of actors is a nice debugging technique.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the time the book was written, there was only one sort of actors: thread-based actors. So if `self` was called on different objects from the same thread, it returned the same `Actor`. Since Scala 2.8 (I think) this no longer holds.

The way shell works is by creating anonymous classes for each sent input, so in the first case you have

```
object $1 {
  self ! "Hello"
}

object $2 {
  self.receive { case x => x }
}
```

and `$1.self` is different from `$2.self`, while in the second case you have

```
object $3 {
  self ! "Hello" ; self.receive { case x => x }
}
```